# On Android simple-xml serial.read() throws StackOverflowError

Tags: java, android, simple-framework

I'm trying to learn to use xml in Java (Android platform, using Eclipse and simple-xml-2.5.2).
I keep getting a weird java.lang.StackOverflowError in the "serial.read" line in "Training.java".
Can you help fixing the problem? Is it an xml definition error?

I include the source below:

File beacons.java:

```
package com.marcos.training;

import java.util.List;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;

@Element
public class Beacons {
    @ElementList(inline=true)
    private List<Beacon> list;

    @Element
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
       return id;
    }

    public Integer getSize() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public List<Beacon> getList() {
       return list;
    }
}
```

File Beacon.java:

```
package com.marcos.training;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
public class Beacon {

    @Attribute
    protected String ssid;

    @Element
    protected String bssid;

    public String getSsid() {
       return ssid;
    }

    public String getBssid() {
      return bssid;
   }
}
```

File Training.java:

```
package com.marcos.training;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException;

public class Training extends Activity {
private final static String TAG = Training.class.getCanonicalName();
TextView textStatus;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);

        Serializer serial = new Persister();

        try {
            Beacons myBeacons;
            try {
                myBeacons = serial.read(Beacons.class, getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.beacons));
            Log.i(TAG, "Number of Beacons: " + myBeacons.getSize());
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Uncaught exception", e);
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Uncaught exception", e);
            return;
        }

        int len = myBeacons.getSize();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                Beacon b = myBeacons.getList().get(i);
                textStatus.append("Beacon " + (i+1) + "\n");
                textStatus.append(" SSID   : " + b.getSsid() + "\n");
                textStatus.append(" BSSID  : " + b.getBssid() + "\n");
                textStatus.append("\n");;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Uncaught exception", e);
        }
    }
}
```

File beacons.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<beacons id="1">
 <beacon ssid="north">
  <bssid>01:02:03:04:05:06</bssid>
 </beacon>
 <beacon ssid="east">
  <bssid>02:03:04:05:06:07</bssid>
 </beacon>
 <beacon ssid="south">
  <bssid>03:04:05:06:07:08</bssid>
 </beacon>
 <beacon ssid="west">
  <bssid>04:05:06:07:08:09</bssid>
 </beacon>
</beacons>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting your XML file into the XML directory of the resources, the Android build system is assuming you want that compiled down into a binary format and it obliges you. Therefore, when you access that input stream and then try to treat it as a textual XML representation it just doesn't work. You have 2 choices.

1. Move your XML file into the `res\raw` directory.
2. Leave it where it is and use the `getResources().getXml(R.xml.beacons)` API and create a pull parser for your particular XML.

See [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! That was really te solution! You saved my day :-)